# Linux - Grep and process substitution

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, grep

I am trying to understand the difference between the commands below.
I have the same file on two machines (Server1 and Server2), as below:

```
$ ls
file1.txt
$ ssh Server2 'ls /tmp/leo/'
file1.txt
```

The command below works as expected:

```
$ ls /tmp/leo/ | grep -f <(ls /tmp/leo/)
file1.txt
```

But if I put SSH on the process substitution command, it don't work:

```
$ ls /tmp/leo/ | grep -f <(ssh l1558s 'ls /tmp/leo/')
```

So what is the difference using SSH?

Regards,
Leo

Comment: please elaborate on "doesn't work"

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - The command don't return the file name, as the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ssh` with the `-n` switch so it doesn't await input on standard input.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But could you explain more about it? I am reading ssh man, but I don't undestand why it was expecting something on stdin.

Comment: @Azize: That's how `ssh` works. It makes it possible to do things like `echo ls | ssh machine`. But in this case, you want `grep` to read from stdin, not `ssh`.